# Create a Self-Signed SSL Certificate for Apache in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl

I want to create A self-signed certificate to encrypt communication between my server and any clients:

I create a self-signed key and certificate pair with OpenSSL in a single command:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
```

but I see this on the logs:

```
[Mon Sep 27 13:42:01.478245 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 1344:tid 139789990751552] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate 176.57.122.225:443:0 for stapling
[Mon Sep 27 13:42:01.485956 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 1345:tid 139789990751552] AH01906: 176.57.122.225:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Sep 27 13:42:01.486039 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 1345:tid 139789990751552] AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: can't retrieve issuer certificate! [subject: CN=176.57.122.225,OU=discoter,O=discoter,L=Brux
elles,ST=Bruxelles,C=BE / issuer: CN=176.57.122.225,OU=discoter,O=discoter,L=Bruxelles,ST=Bruxelles,C=BE / serial: 2AD0C83CF40FCE881CCF862D5D1372957C7C3DF6 / notbefore: Sep 27 13:41:36 2021 GMT / notaft
er: Sep 27 13:41:36 2022 GMT]
[Mon Sep 27 13:42:01.486045 2021] [ssl:error] [pid 1345:tid 139789990751552] AH02604: Unable to configure certificate 176.57.122.225:443:0 for stapling
```

and

```
more /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName 176.58.122.XXX
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does your apache config have `SSLUseStapling On`?

Comment: See [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslusestapling), maybe it can help you to solve the issue.